# CakePHPのControllerにおいて$this->dataと$this->request->dataの意味は同じ？

Tags: cakephp

お世話になります。

私はいまCakePHPを学んでいるのですが、
紹介ページによって
POSTやGETの値を取得する方法が
２種類あることに気づき、困惑しています。
・$this->data
・$this->request->data
中身をみたところ、同じ内容が入っているようなのですが
何か違いがあるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: CakePHPは歴史が古く、Google等の検索では10年以上前の記事や古いバージョンについての記事が出てきてしまいがちです。情報については、まず公式サイトのcookbook  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/index.html を参照してください。また検索で探す場合は記事の投稿日、CakePHPのバージョンを確認するようにしてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->data` はバージョン1系の古い記法であり非推奨です。

CakePHP バージョン3.4以降であれば、 `$this->request->getData()` が推奨される書き方です。
バージョン2系やバージョン3系の3.3以前なら `$this->request->data()` で取得します。

また、`$this->request->data['User']['email']` のような呼び出しは、キーが存在しない場合にエラーが発生するので、`$this->request->data（'User.email'）`, `$this->request->getData（'User.email'）` のようにメソッドで取得すべきです。

リクエストとレスポンスオブジェクト - 2.x https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/controllers/request-response.html#post

リクエストとレスポンスオブジェクト - 3.6 https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/controllers/request-response.html#id5